# WPF Window - Fade Different parts of the same window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, transparency

I have a basic WPF windows with the markup as specific below:

```
<Window x:Class="Application.SomeWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="SomeWindow"
        Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None" Height="39" Width="400"
        ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False"
        WindowStartupLocation="Manual" Background="Transparent"
        Closing="Window_Closing" AllowsTransparency="True" Opacity="0">
   <Border Background="CornflowerBlue" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" Opacity="0.75">
      <Grid>
         <!-- Display bar -->
         <Image Grid.Row="1" Height="24" Margin="7,7,0,0" Name="img1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="/Application;component/Images/dashboard/1.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="13" />
         <Image Height="24" Margin="19,7,47,0" Name="image21" Source="/Application;component/Images/dashboard/2.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
         <!-- Button 1 -->
         <Button Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Height="27" Margin="0,5,25,0" Name="btn1" Click="btn1_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="23" ToolTip="1">
            <Image Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Name="img1" Source="/Application;component/Images/dashboard/3.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22" Stretch="Fill" />
         </Button>
         <!-- Button 2 -->
         <Button Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Height="27" Margin="0,5,5,0" Name="btn2" Click="btn2_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="23" ToolTip="2">
            <Image Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Name="img2" Source="/Application;component/Images/dashboard/4.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22" Stretch="Fill" />
         </Button>
      </Grid>
   </Border>
</Window>
```

Here is what it looks like  now:

[image: How this currently renders visually.]

What I'd really like to do is make it so that initially looks like this:

[image]

Then, once mouseover happens, to fade background opacity in from 0 so it looks like the first image.  The problem is that if I set the `Border` or `Grid` `Background` color to `Transparent` with the goal of fading in on mouseover, then everything *inside* the `Border` or `Grid` is affected as well.

Is there a way to manage the opacities of window and its UI elements seperately?  Or perhaps there is a totally different route to take to get this background fade on mouseover?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options. Number one is to just move the outer border inside the grid, as the first child (and have the other controls alongside it, not in it). That way it will fade by itself, but still be behind the other controls. You will of course either have to set `ColumnSpan`/`RowSpan`, or wrap the entire thing in another `Grid`.

The second option is to just fade the background, not the entire border:

```
<Border ...>
    <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="CornflowerBlue" Opacity="0.5"/>
    </Border.Background>
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this.  It also looks promising just having multiple sibling Grids with the same Grid.Row, then manipulating opacities independently.

Answer (score 0):

try this trick - draw a rectangle or border with dimensions bind to parent or ElementName.
It won't affect rest of elements of tree. Works for me.

```
<Grid x:Name="abc">
                <Border
                    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=abc}"
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=abc}"
                    Background="Blue"
                    Opacity="0.5"/>
                //buttons or inner grid
                  ...
</Grid>
```

If you don'w want to use ElementName, simply replace Width and Height by

```
Width="{Binding ActualWidth, Source={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}"
Height="{Binding ActualHeight, Source={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}"
```

Comment: The width/height there isn't neccessary. A `Border` will by default stretch to fit it's container. (`HorizontalAlignment` & `VerticalAlignment` defaults to `Stretch`)

Comment: You're right. Firstly i write an example with `rectangle`, in that case it made sense. How do you thing, should I edit an answer and delete those lines ?

Comment: Not sure, haven't been here very long...!